# Как достать ближайшее значение

Tags: python, django, postgresql

У меня есть модель с полями: название места, широта, долгота

```
 ​class​ ​Places​(​models​.​Model​): 
 ​    ​author​ ​=​ ​models​.​ForeignKey​(​settings​.​AUTH_USER_MODEL​, ​on_delete​=​models​.​CASCADE​, ​related_name​=​"places"​) 
 ​    ​name​ ​=​ ​models​.​CharField​(​max_length​=​400​, ​verbose_name​=​"Поиск"​, ​null​=​True​, ​blank​=​False​) 
 ​    ​places_long​: ​float​ ​=​ ​models​.​FloatField​(​verbose_name​=​"Долгота места"​, ​null​=​True​, ​blank​=​True​) 
 ​    ​places_lat​: ​float​ ​=​ ​models​.​FloatField​(​verbose_name​=​"Широта места"​, ​null​=​True​, ​blank​=​True​)
```

В которой уже условно есть "места" с их координатами.

Задача такая - у меня есть координаты моего местоположения, есть ли в джанго queryset для поиска ближайшего значения в базе.

Например:

```
мои координаты = [78.431843, 45.753894]

поля в базе:
[1| "место 1"| 53.575932| 89.574847]
[2| "место 2"| 77.385397| 53.807525]
[3| "место 3"| 98.486537| 72.532747]
```

в результате я должен получить 2 строку.

Пока ничего лучше чем делать запрос с фильтром на определённый радиус не нашёл:

​        ​

```
places​ ​=​ ​Places​.​objects​.​filter​( 
 ​           places_lat​__lte​=​(​float​(​lat1​) ​+​ ​5​), places_long__lte​=​(​float​(​long1​) ​+​ ​5​), 
 ​            places_lat__gte​=​(​float​(​lat1​) ​-​ ​5​),places_long​__gte​=​(​float​(​long1​) ​-​ ​5​)).​first​()
```

но у этого есть проблема, если в радиус 5 входит несколько мест, то вытянется первое по порядку, а не ближайшее

Answer (score 0):

Уже не надо, решил задачу через агрегацию

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Если решили самостоятельно, добавьте решение в ответ. "Разобрался самостоятельно" ответом не является, поле "ваш ответ" предназначено для полноценных ответов.